# If write to Firestore while offline doesn't appear in next non-cached return, does that ensure write's failure?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

If a write to Firestore while the client is offline does not appear in that client's listener's subsequent non-cached return, is that a guarantee that that write will never be written to the database? Or is it possible that:

1. We attempt to write while the app is offline and when connection is reestablished, the first non-cached return is from an update by another client writing to the same document/collection which does not contain our cached write.
2. We attempt to write while the app is offline and when connection is reestablished, the first non-cached return does not contain our cached write for no other reason than that our write is still waiting to be written.

Comment: *"If a write to Firestore while the client is offline does not appear in that client's listener's subsequent non-cached return"* - Are you asking because you actually observed this?  If so, could you edit the question to provide more information?

Comment: @DougStevenson no, I'm constructing a method with enough complexity and headache-potential that I want to know if I need to account for this or not upfront.